# Converting a PDF to an Elevation GeoTIFF with QGIS to be imported into Drone Deploy

Tags: qgis, pdf, geopdf

Is it possible to convert a PDF drawing of a final grade plan, using QGIS into an elevation GeoTIFF to be imported into Drone Deploy?

Comment: if so I a can e-mail the file to who ever may be interested.

Comment: You can convert a pdf to a geotiff using the georeferencer (Raster > Georeferencer...).